# Celery： client_recent_max_output_buffer and connected_clients continue to increase in redis

Tags: python, redis, celery

I use celery as MQ for a project about face recognition.

I have three task queues "task_gpu0, task_gpu1, task_download" to provide service for gunicorn flask server, which uses redis as broker and backend.

When I use jmeter to stress the server, after about 20 min, the program raise a exception:

> OperationalError: Error 104 while writing to socket. Connection reset by peer.

On checking redis log, I find client_recent_max_output_buffer and connected_clients continue to increase in info clients. But when I check the key-value by redis desktop manager, the result is ok.

I don't know why the redis output buffer and connected_clients continue to increase.

redis log:

```
:15:M 01 Apr 2019 09:11:18.113 # Client id=58081 addr=172.16.3.22:33832 fd=54 name= age=428 idle=0 flags=P db=1 sub=74995 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=79 qbuf-free=32689 obl=0 oll=452 omem=9267808 events=rw cmd=subscribe scheduled to be closed ASAP for overcoming of output buffer limits.

info clients:
connected_clients:587
client_recent_max_input_buffer:4
client_recent_max_output_buffer:55524832
blocked_clients:2
```

task_download.py

```
from celery import Celery
app = Celery()
app.config_from_object("celery_app_tmp.celeryconfig")

@app.task
def download(addImageInput, faceSetId):
    download_someting()
    return result_dict
```

task0.py is same as task1.py

```
from celery import Celery
app = Celery()
app.config_from_object("celery_app_tmp.celeryconfig")

@app.task
def faceRec(addImageInput, faceSetId):
    do someting()
    return result_dict
```

celeryconfig.py

```
from kombu import Queue
from kombu import Exchange

result_serializer = 'msgpack'
task_serializer = 'msgpack'
accept_content = ['json', 'msgpack']

broker_url = "redis://:redis@172.16.3.22:7369/1"
result_backend = "redis://:redis@172.16.3.22:7369/1"

worker_concurrency = 8

result_exchange_type = 'direct'
result_expires = 5

task_queues = (
    Queue('gpu_0', exchange=Exchange('gpu_0'), routing_key='gpu_0'),
    Queue('gpu_1', exchange=Exchange('gpu_1'), routing_key='gpu_1'),

)

task_routes = {

                'celery_app_tmp.task0.faceRec': {'queue': 'gpu_0', 'routing_key': 'gpu_0'},
                'celery_app_tmp.task1.faceRec': {'queue': 'gpu_1', 'routing_key': 'gpu_1'},
                'celery_app_tmp.task_download.download': {'queue': 'download', 'routing_key': 'download'},
                'celery_app_tmp.task_download.delFile': {'queue': 'download', 'routing_key': 'download'}
}
```

main.py

```
import celery_app_tmp.task0
import celery_app_tmp.task1
import celery_app_tmp.task_download


result_exc = chain(celery_app_tmp.task_download.download.s(addImageInput), random.choice(list_task).faceRec.s(faceSetId))()
while True:
    if result_exc.ready():
        dict_exc = result_exc.get()
        break
```

Comment: Seems to be a celery pub/sub issue https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4983